# Проблема с кодировкой при записи в sqlite3

Tags: python, utf-8, sqlite3, python-2.x

Пишу в Windows 7 на python 2.7.10.

```
#-*-coding: utf-8 -*-
conn = db.connect('main.db')
#conn.text_factory = str
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('PRAGMA encoding="UTF-8";')
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user
 (login text, password text) ''')

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS service
 (username text, service_name text, service_login text, service_pwd text)''')

print u"Добро пожаловать в менеджер паролей"
print u"Разрешены только буквы латинского алфавита и цифры"
name = raw_input(u"Представьтесь: ").strip()
#name.decode('utf-8')
c.execute("SELECT COUNT(login) FROM user WHERE user.login=?", (name,))
```

Насколько мне известно формат строк в sqlite3 по умолчанию имеет кодировку utf-8. При попытке записать имя пользователя русскими буквами в базу sqlite3 получаю ошибку:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "D:/project/pwd/pwd.py", line 30, in <module>
>   `c.execute("SELECT COUNT(login) FROM user WHERE user.login=?", (name,))`
>   `sqlite3.ProgrammingError`: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings
>   unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings
>   (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead
>   just switch your application to Unicode strings.

Если использовать `name.decode('utf-8')` ,то ошибка другая:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "D:/project/pwd/pwd.py", line 29, in <module>
>   `name.decode('utf-8')`
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in `decode`
>   `return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)`
>   `UnicodeDecodeError`: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 0:
>   invalid continuation byte

Вычитал, что можно использовать `conn.text_factory = str`, при этом в базу пишутся русские буквы, но этого делать не рекомендуется и при этом буквы имеют вид:
[image: русские буквы в БД]

Как же всё-таки записать в базу русские имена, чтобы они при этом выглядели нормально?

Попутно хочу спросить, как отловить сразу два exception (`UnicodeDecodeError` и `TypeError`) в конструкции try - exception которые возникают в случае, если пользователь ввёл не ту фразу с которой был зашифрован его пароль к какому-либо сервису:

```
try:
    print u'пароль \t- ', aes.decrypt(i[1]).decode('utf-8')
except: UnicodeDecodeError(u'Неправильная секретная фраза')
```

P.S. пробую так:

```
print name.decode('cp1251').encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
```

печатает Сергей - т.е. как бы всё в utf-8, но ошибка всё равно есть:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "D:/project/pwd/pwd.py", line 32, in <module>
>   `c.execute("SELECT COUNT(login) FROM user WHERE user.login=?", (name,))`
>   `sqlite3.ProgrammingError`: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.

**Обновление**

Пробую так:

```
name = 'Сергей'
print name.decode('cp1251').encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')
```

Т. е. как бы всё в utf-8, но ошибка всё равно есть:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "D:/project/pwd/pwd.py", line 32, in <module>
>   `c.execute("SELECT COUNT(login) FROM user WHERE user.login=?", (name,))`
>   `sqlite3.ProgrammingError`: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.

Comment: name.decode('cp1251').encode('utf-8')

Comment: пробовал, также как и в первом случае ошибка

Comment: Другой вариант: unicode(name)

Comment: а разве не надо указывать символ кодирования?

Comment: name = unicode(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: c try разобрался

Answer (score 1):

При работе с консолью в windows используется кодировка cp866.  Именно по этой причине происходит ошибка кодирования.

Попробуйте перевести из cp866 в utf-8

```
name = name.decode('cp866').encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: тестировал я не в консоле, а в pycharm

Comment: Pycharm скорее всего работает с python через консоль windows, как через посредника.

Comment: нет, в винде он работает через 1251, а в консоле 866. И кстати, сейчас в линуксе прекрасно записываются и русские имена(без крякозбров) и пароли в базу.

Comment: К чему гадать и хардкодить кодировку входящей строки (на одной машине она одна, на другой, другая), если ее можно узнать? print sys.stdin.encoding из cmd на моей машине дает "cp437", из IDE "utf-8". На линуксах, по всей видимости, тоже utf-8, вот все и работет.